# How to Upload a Video?

Tags: php, flash, video, file-upload

I want to know how to upload a **video** like on youtube, vimeo etc to get a final `flash` video. I'm using PHP.

I have this HTML form:

```
<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="upload_video" />
</form>
```

So what should I do if the user has uploaded a video for example in `.mov` or other video formats to have the final `flash` video?

*Please if you know any links or anything related to this let me know!*

Comment: You will need to convert it to a format that people can view. I suggest looking at VideoForEverybody (http://camendesign.com/code/video_for_everybody)

Comment: You can also try out of the box scripts like http://www.phpmotion.com/

Answer (score 2):

This is more of a encoding question.

Install ffmpeg on your server.

See http://vexxhost.com/blog/2007/05/20/how-to-convertencode-files-to-flv-using-ffmpeg-php/

Answer (score 1):

I suggest:

- To check this library [Swfobject](http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/) that help you to insert a flash player in your webpage.
- Then you have to install a video player in your website. For example:[JW Player](http://www.longtailvideo.com/players/---) which has an API that you can use in order to personalize as follow:
- Video in **FLV** and **MP4** and audio in **AAC** (provider=video).
- Sounds in **MP3** (provider=sound).
- Images in **JPG**, **GIF** and **PNG** (provider=image).

In addition this player use the official Youtube API and you the player includes native support for playing back **Youtube** videos just assigning the file **flashvar** to the **URL** of the Youtube video (e.g. `http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2kHbgyGp-R8&feature=related`).